# Couldn't get Google custom search results using JSON

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, google-search-api

I'm developing an application that makes use of Google custom search api as a feature. I added a new custom search and included some sites to search, I was able to do a search and get the results I need, but all of a sudden it stopped returning results. It returns  an empty array instead. I didn't alter anything, but it looks like I have a limited number of queries, am I right?

Here's the line of code responsible for query a search word:

```
NSString *search = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?start=1&ie=utf8&key=XXXXXX&cx=XXXXX&q=SEARHWORD&alt=json"];  
url = [NSURL URLWithString:[search stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
NSURLRequest *request = [[NSURLRequest alloc]initWithURL:url];
NSURLConnection *searchConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc]initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
```

Then the normal steps of parsing the results.

Answer (score 0):

if it was working fine, and then stopped all of a sudden, you may have hit the limit.

You can double check by copy-pasting

`https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?start=1&ie=utf8&key=XXXXXX&cx=XXXXX&q=SEARHWORD&alt=json`

in a browser and seeing the response

Comment: File not found
Firefox can't find the file at https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?start=1&ie=utf8&key=ْْْMYKEYGOESHERE&cx=CXGOESHERE&q=helloworld&alt=json.

    *   Check the file name for capitalization or other typing errors.
    *   Check to see if the file was moved, renamed or deleted.